# Stop/Start the execution of a step function programatically

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-step-functions, serverless-framework-step-functions

I have a step function (stateA) which run indefinitely and another stepfunction (stateB) whose execution typically last for around 2-3 days. Execution of stateB takes precedence over state A. I'm looking to run stateA from 12 AM to 12 PM and stateB for the remaining duration, How do I achieve that ?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve here. By "step function" do you mean state machine, executions or individual states in a state machine? Are they running concurrently?

Answer (score 0):

The APIs to programatically start and stop executions are [StartExecution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_StartExecution.html) and [StopExecution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_StopExecution.html). I don't think that's what you're trying to ask though.